# Unable to build empty android project

Tags: java, android, xml, netbeans

I'm totally a newbie at android development and working on Netbeans 8.0.2 with nbandroid plugin supported by jdk 7.80. My android sdk has sdk tools v 25.2.5, sdk platform tools v 25.0.3 and sdk build tools v 25.0.2. But whenever I try to build the project in netbeans, it shows errors and build process fails.

Following is the console log:

```
ant -f C:\\Users\\admin\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\gary debug
Android SDK Tools Revision 25.2.5
Installed at C:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk
Project Name: gary
Project Type: Application
Using latest Build Tools: 25.0.2
Resolving Build Target for gary...
Project Target:   Android 4.0
API level:        14
WARNING: No minSdkVersion value set. Application will install on all Android versions.
----------
Creating output directories if needed...
Created dir: C:\Users\admin\Documents\NetBeansProjects\gary\bin\rsObj
Created dir: C:\Users\admin\Documents\NetBeansProjects\gary\bin\rsLibs
----------
Resolving Dependencies for gary...
Library dependencies:
No Libraries
------------------
API<=15: Adding annotations.jar to the classpath.
----------
Building Libraries with 'debug'...
No sub-builds to iterate on
Found Deleted Target File
Merging AndroidManifest files into one.
Manifest merger disabled. Using project manifest only.
Handling aidl files...
No AIDL files to compile.
----------
Handling RenderScript files...
----------
Handling Resources...
Found Deleted Target File
Generating resource IDs...
----------
Handling BuildConfig class...
Generating BuildConfig class.
Compiling 2 source files to
C:\Users\admin\Documents\NetBeansProjects\gary\bin\classes
input: C:\Users\admin\Documents\NetBeansProjects\gary\bin\classes
input: C:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk\tools\support\annotations.jar
Pre-Dexing C:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk\tools\support\annotations.jar -> annotations-23306d58b89c9a8e6e1479880a70ed77.jar
java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/android/dx/command/Main : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(Unknown Source)
Exception in thread "main" 
C:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk\tools\ant\build.xml:888: The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk\tools\ant\build.xml:890: The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk\tools\ant\build.xml:902: The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk\tools\ant\build.xml:283: null returned: 1
BUILD FAILED (total time: 2 seconds)
```

Comment: What happens if your project is not empty, but you have one line of code which prints "Hello World" to screen?

Comment: then also, same error

Comment: Maybe you should fix this `Unsupported major.minor version 52.0`. Replace it with a valid Android version. Try 21, 22, 23 or 24 and report back. I guess you wanted to type 25, not 52.

Comment: again same errors....and i typed right... it's 52 .... @JonZarate

Comment: What is 52 ? Show us your Gradle file

Comment: i told you sir, i'm a newbie......what's gradle file?

Comment: You may be a newbie, but you have a brain and a computer, do some research.

Comment: If you are absolutely newbie then why on earth do you insist doing android development with netbeans? It would be much easier to go with the stream and use android studio.

Comment: i already tried android studio....but it's very slow..... i like netbeans ide the most